# Column does not exist (SQLAlchemy / PostgreSQL): Trouble with quotation marks

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Im having trouble with a postgresql query using SQLAlchemy.

I created some large tables using this line of code:

```
frame.to_sql('Table1', con=engine, method='multi', if_exists='append')
```

It worked fine. Now, when I want to query data out of it, my first problem is that I have to use quotation marks for each table and column name and I dont really know why, maybe somebody can help me out there.

That is not my main problem though. My main problem is, that when querying the data, all numerical WHERE conditions work fine, but not the ones with Strings in the column data. I get an error that the column does not exist. Im using:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT "variable1", "variable2" FROM "Table1" WHERE "variable1" = 123 AND "variable2" = "abc" ', engine)
```

I think it might be a problem that I use "abc" instead of 'abc', but I cant change it because of the ' signs in the argument of the query. If I change those ' to " then the Column names and Table names are not detected correctly (because of the problem before that they have to be in quotation marks).

This is the error message:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) ERROR:  COLUMN »abc« does not exist
LINE 1: ...er" FROM "Table1" WHERE "variable2" = "abc"
And there is an arrow pointing to the first quotation mark of the "abc".
```

Im new to SQL and I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: it should be: `AND "variable2" = 'abc'`. You cannot quote strings with `"`, btw. you do not need to wrap table names and and columns with double quotes unless it is extremely necessary. Imho it is a bad practice and only leads to confusion. This also works: `SELECT variable1, variable2 FROM Table1 WHERE variable1 = 123 AND variable2 = 'abc' `

Comment: I was guessing that that is the problem. But, when I use 'abc' the quotes cancel out the quotes from the argument and I get a Syntax Error. And when I dont use the double quotes for the table and column it doesnt work - "column doesnt exist".
Maybe I created them weirdly.

Comment: can't you wrap out the whole sql statement with `"`, e.g. `"SELECT variable1, variable2 FROM Table1 WHERE variable1 = 123 AND variable2 = 'abc'"`?

Comment: Then the double quotes of the table and column name cancel out. And if I leave them out, I get the "column doesnt exist" error. I think it has something to do with how I created the table? For other tables I dont need the double quotation

Comment: Yes, that might be the issue! Have you created the table like this `create table "table1" (...`?I really discourage the usage of double quotes for database objects.. it gets really nasty and you might lose a lot of time finding the problem.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure anymore. I thought I didnt, but I might have done that. The tables are really long and it took a long while uploading them, Id rather not do that again. Can I just rename it with a simple command?
Also: When I print the table names of my database, no quotation marks appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Most" SQL dialects (notable exceptions being MS SQL Server and MS Access) strictly differentiate between

- single quotes: for string literals, e.g., `WHERE thing = 'foo'`
- double quotes: for object (table, column) names, e.g., `WHERE "some col" = 123`

PostgreSQL throws in the added wrinkle that table/column names are forced to lower case if they are not (double-)quoted and then uses case-sensitive matching, so if your table is named `Table1` then

- `SELECT * FROM Table1` will fail because PostgreSQL will look for `table1`, but
- `SELECT * FROM "Table1"` will succeed.

The way to avoid confusion in your query is to use query parameters instead of string literals:

```py
# set up test environment
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Table1"')
    conn.exec_driver_sql('CREATE TABLE "Table1" (variable1 int, variable2 varchar(50))')
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(123, "abc"), (456, "def")], columns=["variable1", "variable2"])
df1.to_sql("Table1", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")

# test .read_sql_query() with parameters
import sqlalchemy as sa
sql = sa.text('SELECT * FROM "Table1" WHERE variable1 = :v1 AND variable2 = :v2')
param_dict = {"v1": 123, "v2": "abc"}
df2 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, params=param_dict)
print(df2)
"""
   variable1 variable2
0        123       abc
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be: `AND "variable2" = 'abc'`.

You cannot quote strings/literals with `"`, as PostgreSQL will interpret it as a database object. Btw. you do not need to wrap table names and and columns with double quotes unless it is extremely necessary, e.g. case sensitive object names, names containing spaces, etc. Imho it is a bad practice and on the long run only leads to confusion. So your query could be perfectly written as follows:

```
SELECT variable1, variable2 
FROM table1 
WHERE variable1 = 123 AND variable2 = 'abc';
```

Keep in mind that it also applies for other objects, like tables or indexes.

- `CREATE TABLE Table1 (id int)` - nice.
- `CREATE TABLE "Table1" (id int)` - not nice.
- `CREATE TABLE "Table1" ("id" int)` - definitely not nice ;)

In case you want to remove the unnecessary double quotes from your table name:

```
ALTER TABLE "Table1" RENAME TO table1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f7435d8d3795e2c06c8107b9cc0a8fd6)

Comment: It seems like I used the alternative 3 ;) 

Can delete all quotes with one command? I have 50 columns and would prefer not to do it by hand

Comment: @Elias you don't need to change the column names.. see my fiddle.

Comment: I think the problem is that my columns all start with an uppercase. The same goes for the tablename. I tried changing some columns/table names and as soon as they dont have uppercase letters it works.

Comment: @Elias I see.. the problem is more substantial than I thought :D If this answer does not help you at all, I will delete it.

Comment: I learned that double quotes are bad style, but I also learned they let me access uppercase letters hehe

Comment: @Elias so it worth leaving it here :) cheers and happy coding